# Parent-Child functionality

Tags: facebook, parent-child

Is there a functionality that allows multiple locations of one business to be shown on the main Fan page of a business? What is the best way to display multiple business locations on a single Facebook page?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook has a parent-child Page set up tool to a limited set of businesses that have a corporate-local structure.  Once the connections between parent and child Pages are arranged, parent Pages will include a Locations tab in their Edit Page admin interface navigation menu.

Facebook’s Locations app first appeared in August 2011 as part of a limited private test of parent-child page management tools,  but it seems Facebook is reserving this for select partners for now.

Businesses with access to a Facebook account representative or working with one of Facebook’s Preferred Marketing Developers certified in Pages should connect with those contacts to request access to the app. Other businesses will have to develop their own store locator applications.

[Facebook Parent-Child-Model](http://www.slideshare.net/steph_king/facebook-parent-child-model)

[Facebook updates Locations app, but feature still only available to select pages](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/04/25/facebook-updates-locations-app-but-feature-still-only-available-to-select-pages/)

[Page_Locations PDF](http://ads.ak.facebook.com/ads/FacebookAds/Page_Locations.pdf)

[parent-child-corporate-local-locations-pages-places](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/07/11/parent-child-corporate-local-locations-pages-places/)

[Quora Thread](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-Pages/Is-it-possible-to-add-multiple-locations-to-a-Facebook-Page-for-business)